# How to make empty divs stay one by one with space?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="s-content-style">
   <div class="content">
       <div style="margin-top:5px">11</div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px"></div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px"><b>fff</b></div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px"></div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px"></div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px"></div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px">aaaaaaaaaa</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Empty divs superimposed on each other. How to fix it? I need divs one by one with space.

I tryied:

```
.content{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What you mean *overflowed*? By who?

Comment: @Justinas I mean superimposed on each other

Comment: Why don't you use &nbsp; for empty DIVs?

Comment: @DhavalPanchal coz, i think its bad codding.

Comment: @rantihawk  try `padding-top: 5px` instead of `margin-top: 5px`

Comment: @rantihawk No it is not

Comment: Maybe a picture of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: If I understand correctly (it's very difficult on the basis of your question) you need to use display: inline-bloсk and float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use single and multiple div with using height without `nbsp;` as below:

```css
.content{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="s-content-style">
   <div class="content">
       <div style="margin-top:5px">11</div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px"></div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px"><b>fff</b></div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px;height:5px;"></div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px;height:5px;"></div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px;height:5px;"></div>
       <div style="margin-top:5px">aaaaaaaaaa</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a minimum height for the divs inside your container with class `.content`. If there is content inside the div, the height will increase as needed. If there is no content, the div will still have a minimum height of your defined value. If you set the `min-height` value to the defined line-height of your content, empty divs will always have the same height as a div with only one line of content.

The advantage of using `min-height` is, that you don't need to add different css to empty and non-empty divs. You can style them all at once using one definition.

```css
.content div {
  margin-top: 5px;
  min-height: 18px; /* set to min desired height */
}
```

```html
<div class="s-content-style">
  <div class="content">
    <div>11</div>
    <div></div>
    <div><b>fff</b></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>aaaaaaaaaa</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning @rantihawk,
try this:

```
<div class="s-content-style">
<div class="content">
    <div style="margin-top:5px">11</div>
    <div style="margin-top:5px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="margin-top:5px"><b>fff</b></div>
    <div style="margin-top:5px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="margin-top:5px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="margin-top:5px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="margin-top:5px">aaaaaaaaaa</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thx for answer. Any options without &nbsp; ? I think its bad codding.

Comment: @rantihawk  another solution  `padding-top: 5px` instead of `margin-top: 5px`

Comment: @rantihawk how do &nbsp; is bad?

Comment: @BendyZhang thx, that worked. But why margin not working, just wondering
?

Comment: @rantihawk why bad coding ?
&nbps = non-breaking space, this is used when you want to use a white space in this cases...